How are offsets ranges of x86-64 Linux ABI small code model derived?
The ABI document describes the non-PIC small code model as follows:


I don't understand what is meant by the symbolic references with offsets, in both the sign extended ([-2^{31}, 2^{24}]) and zero extended ([0,2^{31}-2^{24}) case. I also don't get why rip relative offsets are restricted to
[-2^{24}, 2^{24}] How are these numbers derived?
